# Unable to resolve wasted re-renders using memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, rendering, memo

I recently started learning React and I am creating a 2048 game. Now whenever a user performs a move I make certain changes to the grid which therefore updates the state. However with each subsequent key-press the number of times the grid is re-rendered increases exponentially and freezes after a certain point even though there is no change in state (grid's value). The problem persists even after using React.memo. How do I go about resolving these unwanted re-renders and why does it happen?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Cell from "./Cell";
import "./Game.css";

let permittedKeys = [
  "ArrowUp",
  "KeyW",
  "ArrowRight",
  "KeyD",
  "ArrowDown",
  "KeyS",
  "ArrowLeft",
  "KeyA",
];

const boardSize = 4;

function Game() {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState();

  console.log("re-rendering grid", grid);
  //creating a 4x4 board when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    const board = getBoard(boardSize);
    setGrid(board);
  }, []);

  //function that renders all the 4x4 cells
  // CORRECTION - Give every cell a key
  const renderCells =
    grid &&
    grid.map((row, i) => row.map((col, j) => <Cell key={i*boardSize+j} value={grid[i][j]} />));

  //check if a key is pressed
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    //If pressed key is not a valid game control key ignore the keydown event
    if (permittedKeys.indexOf(e.code) === -1) return;

    //Else
    if (grid) setGrid(performMove(e.code, [...grid], boardSize));
  });

  return <div className="board">{renderCells}</div>;
}

const performMove = (pressedKey, board, boardSize) => {
  //Move cells in pressedKey-direction till they hit another block
  //Eg:When left key is pressed
  //256 empty 256 64 becomes
  //256 256 64 empty
  for (let i = 0; i < boardSize; ++i) {
    const newRow = [];
    let count = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j < boardSize; ++j)
      if (board[i][j]) {
        newRow.push(board[i][j]);
        ++count;
      }
    while (count !== boardSize) {
      ++count;
      if (pressedKey === permittedKeys[6] || pressedKey === permittedKeys[7])
        newRow.push(0);
      else if (
        pressedKey === permittedKeys[2] ||
        pressedKey === permittedKeys[3]
      )
        newRow.unshift(0);
    }
    board[i] = newRow;
  }
  return board;
};

//generate the next cell after the player performs a move
function generateNext() {
  return Math.random() < 0.9 ? 2 : 4;
}

function getBoard(boardSize) {
  const board = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < boardSize; ++i) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; ++j) row.push(0);
    board.push(row);
  }
  //generating two random starting cells
  let i1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSize);
  let j1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSize);
  let i2, j2;
  do {
    i2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSize);
    j2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSize);
  } while (i1 === i2 && j1 === j2);

  board[i1][j1] = generateNext();
  board[i2][j2] = generateNext();

  return board;
}

export default React.memo(Game);
```

Comment: On every render you are adding a new `keydown` listener so you get exponentially more `setGrid` calls each render. You shouldn't be adding listeners directly, but rather should be leveraging Reacts event/render cycle.

Comment: @pilchard that worked for me. I added the event listener when the component was mounted instead of doing it in the functional component and it resolved my problem. Thank you!